# How to perform a join on a already joined query?

Tags: python, join, select, sqlalchemy

Say I have a query like so:

```
subquery = select(table1.c.id,
                  table1.c.type,
                  table1.c.some_category,
                  table2.c.some_other_category).join(table2,
                                                     table1.c.id== table2.c.id)
```

I want to use this query to perform another join on a third table.
Like so:

```
# Fetch data
another_query = session.query(table3.c.id,
                              table3.c.aa,
                              table3.c.bb,
                              table3.c.cc,
                              table3.c.dd).subquery()

join = select(another_query.c.id,
              another_query.c.aa).join(subquery,
                                       another_query.c.id== subquery.c.id)

result = session.execute(join).fetchmany(1000)
```

I get the following error: Join target, typically a FROM expression, or ORM relationship attribute expected, got <sqlalchemy.sql.selectable.Select object.

How can I reuse the mentioned select subquery in the join statement?

Comment: You should be able to do so using `alias()` when creating the `join` variable. Some info about this method can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350033/usage-of-aliased-in-sqlalchemy-orm).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query:

```
subquery = select(
    table1.c.id,
    table1.c.type,
    table1.c.some_category,
    table2.c.some_other_category
).join(table2, table1.c.id == table2.c.id)

final_query = select(
    subquery.c.id,
    subquery.c.type,
    subquery.c.some_category,
    subquery.c.some_other_category,
    table3.c.column1,
    table3.c.column2
).join(table3, subquery.c.id == table3.c.id)

result = conn.execute(final_query)
```

It should join to your subquery.

Comment: That looks promising. The result is a ChunkedIteratorResult object right? How do I work with this result in order to get that result?

Comment: you can loop in it:

    `for row in result:`
         `id = row['id']`
         `type = row['type']`
         `some_category = row['some_category']`
         `some_other_category = row['some_other_category']`
         `column1 = row['column1']`
         `column2 = row['column2']`